# fluxo para login com web api com usuarios do AD voltando token por perfil

Tags: autenticação, asp.net-web-api, ad

Estamos montando uma Api para os nossos sistemas internos, entramos em um paradigma da melhor forma para se criar um login de usuários validados pelo AD retornando token com perfil sendo o Perfil o grupo que o usuário esta no AD, estamos tentando desenhar a melhor forma para essa implementação, alguém poderia ajudar? Os usuários estão 1 para 1 com o grupo no AD, um usuário so pode estar em um grupo no AD.

Para exemplificar, estamos montando um ADM que irá consumir dados da API que sera em Web Api, para isso precisamos criar uma forma de validação de login que gere um token de acesso por perfil, esse perfis serão os grupos criados no AD, cada usuario estara em um Grupo Ex.: Administradores, Editores ... etc hoje temos 5 e acreditamos que não iremos aumentar, mas podemos criar um Enum ou algo do tipo... a maior duvida é a melhor forma de se implementar essas validações? pensamos no jwt.io, mas tem pouca documentação...

Comment: Eu editei, ficou mais clara @bigown ?